# Can't find resource from css

Tags: css

I can't find solution to load image linked in css. Chrome inspector shows me message:

```
404 (not found)
```

and shows me this link: http://127.0.0.1:5500/components/css/img.png

even if I have in my css

```css
background-image: url(../src/splash_1/img.png)
```

Could anyone please help me with appropriate linking... I can't find answer how to correctly link that image in that folder structure.

UPDATE:
Below in the second picture attached, I added print screen with real data from Chrome Inspector and code and the element. Maybe that will be more helpful. I want to link correctly

```
ccbackground.jpg
```

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to add url path like this: *`background-image: url(./src/splash_1/img.png)`*

Comment: Hi Rohit, Unfortunately it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass the path as a string in single quotes with the same path you tried first. The `..` is needed to step one folder up from the css folder.

```css
background-image: url('../src/splash_1/img.png');
```

*Note:* it can be that the path is cached locally on the client side, you may need to clear browser cache to make it work.

Comment: David, what if this doesn't work despite I clear the cache? What check next? What might be the reason? I am attaching print screen to DevTools and part of the code.

Comment: I see. `background-image: url('../sys_comp/splash_1/img.png');` should work with your structure can't it be a build issue? other changes made on the CSS are visible on the local address correctly?

Comment: (you could also try just opening the index.html without serving the project on localhost if it makes any diffrence in the img path)

Comment: David, css files are visible in index (all changes exluding links works - for example colors). If I put linked files in the css folder, it shows properly..what is going on.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure if I understand correctly your last comment :$ do you mean an absolute path works correctly? do you use any extra build system or any extra local server (like express.js running on Node)?

Comment: David, It turned out I had 2 pairs of the same css files in different location. One pair in correct location and the other in main folder. I was changing css files in editor located in main folder, but in index.html css files were linked to specified folder. So even I changed css it didn't reflect changes in index.html, because the changes were done in the same name css files but in other location. I wonder how it happened I had 2 pairs of css files in different location, this is something really unclear for me. Anyway, I really appreciate your time. Your solution works great! Thank you.

Comment:  I am glad you were able to fix it finally. yeah, sometimes the strangest issues' root cause are us. could you post the solution as a separate answer? it can be useful for others when everything seems correct and the path is still doesn't changing.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually it turned out I had 2 pairs of the same css files in different location. One pair in correct location and the other in main folder. I was changing css files in editor located in main folder, but in index.html css files were linked to specified folder. So even I changed css it didn't reflect changes in index.html, because the changes were done in the same name css files but in other location. I wonder how it happened I had 2 pairs of css files in different location, this is something really unclear for me. Thank you All for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
background-image: url('/src/splash_1/img.png');
```

Comment: Give me your URL adress please :) put the project live @MaciekŁubocki

Comment: Lubo, this is part of bigger project and given part is sample. I can't give you whole code, if this is ok I can paste refered parts of actual code and explain real structure.

Comment: You could create a demo on jsfindle.net @MaciekŁubocki

Comment: I am sorry, I am not fluent at jsfiddle, is it possible to emulate folder structure there? I have no problem with linking sources from the net, only local linking / I think problem with correct folder structure. When I put img.png inside css folder, graphics from image display right away.

Comment: Try to post it here

Comment: Lubo I updated main thread with the actual code, maybe that will helps?

Comment: @MaciekŁubocki Muhammad bellow here posted new possible solution, check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code...

```
background-image: url('components/src/splash_1/img.png');
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad for your input in solving this case. Unfortunately it doesn't work.